# How to define avro schema for complex json document?

Tags: json, database, apache-kafka, avro, confluent-platform

**THIS IS AN EXAMPLE OF MY JSON:**

```
{"ID":2,"name":"Donatello","lastname":"Di Niccoló","age":23,"hobbies":["reading","dancing",{"sports":["rafting","baseball"]}],"address":{"street":"Tepito", "number":"77", "districts":"Benito Juárez", "country": "CDMX"}}
```

**THIS IS MY AVRO SCHEMA**

```
{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[ 
{"name":"ID","type":"int"}, 
{"name":"name", "type": "string"},
{"name":"lastname", "type": "string"},
{"name":"age", "type": "int"},
{"name":"hobbies","type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
        "type": "array", "items": "string",
        "type":"record","name":"myhobbies",
        "fields":[
                    {"name":"sports","type":{"type": "array", "items": "string"}}
                ]
}       }
},
{"name":"address","type":{"type":"record","name":"myaddress",
    "fields":[
    {"name":"street","type":"string"},
    {"name":"number","type":"string"},
    {"name":"districts","type":"string"},
    {"name":"country","type":"string"}
    ]

}
}
]}
```

> I need the avro format couse i wanna start a producer whit kafka but when i start it,  have a mistake when i enter the previos one record. Couse the avro schema does not match with the record. How make them match

---

```
Yeah Nitin Tripathi

{"type":"record","name":"myrecord","fields":[ 
{"name":"ID","type":"int"}, 
{"name":"name", "type": "string"},
{"name":"lastname", "type": "string"},
{"name":"age", "type": "int"},
{"name":"hobbies","type": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
        "type":"record","name":"myhobbies",
        "fields":[
                    {"name":"sports","type":{"type": "array", "items": "string"}}
                ]
}       }
},
{"name":"address","type":{"type":"record","name":"myaddress",
    "fields":[
    {"name":"street","type":"string"},
    {"name":"number","type":"string"},
    {"name":"districts","type":"string"},
    {"name":"country","type":"string"}
    ]

}
}
]}
```

I tried it, but it does not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Arrays use the type name "array" and support a single attribute, however, the schema for hobbies mixes string and myhobbies type